# JavaScript emptying the input after autocomplete select

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have this code which is working fine, but I want to empty the input $project 
after the user select an autocomplete suggestion..

```
   $project.autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: projects,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
         $project.val(ui.item.label);
         return false;
      },
      select: function (e, ui) {
         createTag(ui.item.label, ui.item.id);
    }
  });
```

where to place this code in order to perform the action after the autocomplete is triggered ?

```
 //document.getElementById("project").value = "";
```

Comment: Hi, place inside the `select: function (e, ui) { ..... }` will do the trick

Comment: Hi, I tried it didn't work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-close):

```js
var projects = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];

var $project = $( "#tags" );
$project.autocomplete({
  minLength: 1,
  source: projects,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $project.val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  },
  close: function (e, ui) {
    e.target.value = '';
    //createTag(ui.item.label, ui.item.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I've spent a lot of time on it !

Comment: @Tony Thank you so much for sharing your problem. I tested it using your updated answer (i.e.: your code and it works on my computer). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
select: function (e, ui) {
     $project.val("");
     createTag(ui.item.label, ui.item.id);
}
```

Comment: I also tried this .. didn't work.. in fact I think the text is filled in the input after the select, so I want to trigger an action that occur even after the select ..

Comment: I would need details about autocomplete plugin and createTag functions to help further